# Is there a rule for the KeyError argument?

Tags: python

Normally, the `KeyError` argument (`err.args[0]`) is the key that caused the failed lookup (demo at the bottom).
Is this some kind of a rule that should be obeyed? The documentation of the `KeyError` does not say anything about the argument, but maybe it is written elsewhere ...

The related code is:

```
try:
    item = mapping[key]
except KeyError:
    # each error will be logged, a meaningful message should be provided
    raise KeyError(f"Item {key} was not found in something") from None
```

---

A little demo:

```
empty = {}
for key in 42, "abc", True, None, 3.14, ('tu','ple'):
    try:
        empty[key]
    except KeyError as err:
        assert err.args[0] == key 
        print(f"{key} not found")
```

Comment: Interesting question. I would suggest adding an example where you catch a `KeyError` generated by Python itself. Your text now mentions `err.args[0]` and I assume that `err` is the thing in `except KeyError as err`, but it might be better to make this explicit. I guess you want to raise a KeyError and are concerned about assumptions made by other code that catches this exeption?

Comment: @wovano Yes, that is my concern.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be closed as "opinion-based". The question is about a (possibly/hopefully documented) rule regarding the use of built-in exceptions. It's not asking for unwritten rules / personal opinions, AFAICT. There either is a written requirement/recommendation (on docs.python.org or in a PEP), or there isn't. Either way, this could probably be answered with facts.